# Disconnecting a connected graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I need to find the minimum number of edges that need to be removed from a connected graph (which may have cycles and has unweighted undirected edges) so that i end up with two given nodes - A and B in separate disconnected parts.

Input: Edges, Node A, Node B. (There exists at least 1 path from A to B)
Output: Minimum number of edges to be removed so that there remains no path between A & B

I can only think of the worst solution:-

```
best = no. of edges in the given connected graph G
For each possible subset S of Edges in the given connected graph G
   Graph temp = G minus edges S
   if there exists a path between A and B in temp
       continue
   else
        best = Min(best, no. of edges in S)
return best
```

I'm looking for a solution which would work comfortably for a graph with 15 vertices within a second or two.
I wonder if my solution is good enough.

Thanks!

P.s. I'm not sure whether the big O complexity of my solution is 2^n or n*(2^n) or (n^2)*(2^n). I think its the latter but I would like to know for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [maximum flow algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem) to compute the minimum cut between A and B in your graph.

Runtime: O(n*m) with an excess-scaling [push-relabel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push%E2%80%93relabel_maximum_flow_algorithm) variant (since you have only unit capacities).

Your solution is O(2^m * (n + m)) if you use DFS or BFS for reachability in the fixed subgraph.

Comment: Thanks for the super quick answer. The wikipedia article's going way over my head though. But i'm reading. i guess i really need to study more graph theory fundamentals

Comment: @user3557625 For starters, you might want to look at [Edmonds-Karp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm), which is a simple yet reasonably efficient max-flow algorithm. You could also use a library, most graph algorithm libraries should be able to solve max-flow :)

Comment: Also, i would appreciate if you could comment on my pseudo code - i.e. if it even counts as a solution. If so is it is likely to be unacceptably slow for n~15? Although Of course once i understand the maximum flow algorithm i shouldnt need that anymore!

Comment: @user3557625 If the graph is connected, your pseudocode depends more on the number of edges than number of nodes. It's something like m*2^m where m is the number of edges, so yes, it well get out of hand very quickly for m above 25 or so